# MySql inner join takes more than 10 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables posts and followings

```
posts (id,userid,post,timestamp) 30 000 rows
```

and

```
followings(id_me,userid) 90 000 rows
```

I want to get lattest 10 posts form posts table based on the people i follow and my posts

```
SELECT p.*
 FROM posts as p INNER JOIN
     followings as f
     ON (f.id_me=(my user id) AND p.userid=f.userid )
        OR 
        p.userid=(my user id)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

But it takes about 10-15 seconds to return. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post an `EXPLAIN` on the query? Also table structure might be helpful (existing indexes)

Comment: Can we see the actual query, and the EXPLAIN, and the DDLs for the relevant tables?

Comment: You may try and make userid and id_me as indexes on the table see if that helps.

Comment: Try STRAIGHT JOIN
AND don't use order by if not necessary it makes ur request 5 times heavy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove the filter from the join clause, let the join just correlate the joining tables.

```
(
SELECT p.*
 FROM posts as p
  INNER JOIN followings as f ON p.userid=f.userid
  where f.id_me=(my user id)
UNION
SELECT p.*
 FROM posts as p
  where p.userid=(my user id)
)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

second, verify your indexes if that ids got no indexes it ill perform a full table scan for each cartesian product of both tables (30k x 90k =~ 3700k pairs being compared)

third, if you don't follow yourself you need a union from post you are following and your posts

Comment: i have index for userid column in posts and (id_me,userid) in followings

Comment: i think your ON condition excludes my posts cause i dont follow myself

Comment: Edited my answer to meet that "not following myself" requirement.

Comment: Thanks it worked about 0.05 seconds do u mean i should follow myself?

Comment: I guess the problem was that OR on join clause causing a outter join. The union removed that and the engine is "sorting" out your posts and posts you are following. After that the order by is applied to a smaller set

Comment: I think if i follow myself i dont need second part (p.userid=my user id) cause there is f.userid=my user id in the following table

Comment: Sure, you are right. If you followed yourself so eventually f.userid = d.id_me.

Answer (score 0):

Using an OR in SQL is a performance killer, try this:

```
SELEC p.*
FROM posts as p INNER JOIN
 followings as f
 ON (f.id_me=(my user id) AND p.userid IN (f.userid,(my user id)))
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: without the OR part it still takes about 10 seconds

Comment: what indexes could yo use?  Do you have an idea of an execution plan?

Comment: Do you think that replacing `OR` with `IN` improves efficiency?

Comment: it depends on the plan.  What's missing from the OP question is info related to what plan is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Do this query using `union`:

```
(SELECT p.*
 FROM posts p INNER JOIN
      followings f
      ON (f.id_me=(my user id) AND p.userid=f.userid
)
union
(select p.*
 from posts p
 where p.userid=(my user id)
)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

If the two conditions never overlap, then use `union all` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An `OR` condition like that prevents the query optimizer from making use of indexes. Use a `UNION` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT p.*
      FROM posts as p 
      INNER JOIN followings as f
      ON f.id_me=(my user id) AND p.userid=f.userid

      UNION

      SELECT *
      FROM posts
      WHERE userid = (my user id)) u
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: i used UNIONS too but no luck

Comment: Do you have indexes on the `id_me` and `userid` columns?

Answer (score 0):

It might be just me but I think your `WHERE` clause is in an inefficient location:

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM
    posts p
    INNER JOIN
        followings f
        ON p.userid=f.userid
WHERE
    MyUserID IN (p.userid, f.id_me)
ORDER BY
    id DESC
LIMIT
    10
```

Answer (score 0):

I read in comments that you have the required indexes. The problem is the query. Combining `OR` with a `JOIN` confuses the poor and (often) dumb optimizer. The `LIMIT 10` should be helpful but the optimizer is not (yet) smart enough to make the best plan.

Try this query:

```sql
  ( SELECT p.*
    FROM posts AS p
      JOIN followings AS f
         ON  f.id_me = (my_user_id) 
         AND p.userid = f.userid
    ORDER BY p.id DESC 
    LIMIT 10
  ) 
UNION ALL
  ( SELECT p.*
    FROM posts AS p
    WHERE p.userid = (my_user_id) 
    ORDER BY p.id DESC 
    LIMIT 10
  ) AS x
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10 ;
```